# Proxying between 2 FTP servers for failover using 3rd server

Tags: go, proxy, ftp

I have a 1st ftp server on VDS # 1 (primary), which can sometimes be disabled by hosting. We have created a second VDS # 2 (secondary) that can help with fault tolerance when VDS # 1 is unreachable. VDS # 2 always has the same list of users with VDS # 1, with their usernames, passwords and directory tree.

When users cannot access VDS # 1, we want to automatically redirect them to VDS # 2.
I wrote the GOlang code (code below), but it does not work correctly, I do n't know why, I am new to FTP issues.

[Schematic view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4adk.png)

Can you help me? Perhaps there is a way to easily redirect the FTP request through a special server response or something like that?
Big thanks to all!

```
func proxyConn(connection net.Conn) {

    defer connection.Close()

    remoteServer, remoteServerError := getActiveServer()
    if remoteServerError != nil {
        Error{}.PrintAndSave(remoteServerError.Error())
        return
    }

    remoteConnection, remoteError := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, remoteServer)
    if remoteError != nil {
        Error{}.PrintAndSave(remoteError.Error())
        return
    }
    defer remoteConnection.Close()

    io.Copy(remoteConnection, connection)
    io.Copy(connection, remoteConnection)
}

func getActiveServer() (*net.TCPAddr, error) {

    connectedServerIndex := -1

    for ftpServerIndex, ftpServer := range FTP_SERVERS {
        connectedServer, serverError := net.DialTimeout("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", ftpServer, FTP_DEFAULT_PORT), CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
        if serverError != nil {
            if ftpServerIndex == 0 {
                // Send e-mail "Server unreachable"
            }
        } else {
            connectedServerIndex = ftpServerIndex
            connectedServer.Close()
            break
        }
    }

    if connectedServerIndex == -1 {
        return nil, errors.New("active servers not found")
    }

    return net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", FTP_SERVERS[connectedServerIndex], FTP_DEFAULT_PORT))
}

func main() {

    localAddress, localAddressErr := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", LOCAL_ADDRESS, FTP_DEFAULT_PORT))
    if localAddressErr != nil {
        Error{}.PrintAndSave(localAddressErr.Error())
    }

    server, serverError := net.ListenTCP("tcp", localAddress)
    if serverError != nil {
        Error{}.PrintAndSave(serverError.Error())
        return
    }

    for {
        connection, connectionError := server.Accept()
        if connectionError != nil {
            Error{}.PrintAndSave(fmt.Sprintf("failed to accept listener: %v", connectionError))
        }

        go proxyConn(connection)
    }
}
```

Comment: FTP is notoriously difficult to proxy, because it uses more than one TCP connection per client. You have to intercept and rewrite the client's `PORT` command and/or the server's response to the `PASV` command, and then proxy the data connections dynamically (so far you only proxy the control connection). A simple io.Copy won't cut it for FTP.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter. Maybe you know way to do this easy? Perhaps online service?

Comment: work out which ftp server you need to use and then use this to set a proxy environment variable at the client end.  Alternatively, monitor the two ftp servers and alter DNS (using a short TTL) to give a different canonical name depending on which is up